# why protege appears blue arrow automatically?

Tags: protege

when I followed the official document of protege to set up a pizza ontology,it is OK,but when I open this ontology after saving,I found each class has a grey arrow ahead and some blue arrows (refer the picture1).I take class Pizza and PizzaBase as an example,we know that the relationship between  Pizza and PizzaBase is hasBaase,that is Pizza hasBase some PizzaBase,so I click the Pizza and in class Description,I set that(refer secong picture2),then the class Pizza automatically becomes the subclass of PizzaBase,and a blue arrow appears. there are many blue arrows.I don't know what is the matter,so please help me,thanks very much!  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtHZx.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSmAZ.png)

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share the screenshots

Comment: http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/class-hierarchy/